# How to refresh or reload panel view in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell How to refresh or reload panel view in extjs4.1

Thanks

Comment: actually it depends on what your panel contains? how do we supposed to know that?

Comment: @Nandkumar Tekale I want to refresh the page can you tell how to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually need is to refresh a store that populates your panel view. If you have for example:

```
Ext.define('YourApp.view.YourPanel', {
                extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',                
                alias: 'widget.yourpanel',                               
                store: 'YourPanelStore'
...
```

then in the controller all you need to do is:

```
Ext.getCmp('yourpanel').store.reload();
```

or

```
Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('YourPanelStore').reload();
```